# Is it possible to find the corresponding task_struct from sched_entity?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I know if we have task_struct, surly we can get the contained sched_entity because it's one field in the task struct. But can we get the pointer to the task_struct given the shed_entity? Following is the sched_entity structure:

```
struct sched_entity {
    struct load_weight  load;       /* for load-balancing */
    struct rb_node      run_node;
    struct list_head    group_node;
    unsigned int        on_rq;

    u64         exec_start;
    u64         sum_exec_runtime;
    u64         vruntime;
    u64         prev_sum_exec_runtime;

    u64         nr_migrations;


#ifdef CONFIG_SCHEDSTATS
    struct sched_statistics statistics;
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED
    struct sched_entity *parent;
    /* rq on which this entity is (to be) queued: */
    struct cfs_rq       *cfs_rq;
    /* rq "owned" by this entity/group: */
    struct cfs_rq       *my_q;
#endif
};
```

It seems that there is no place where I can get the task_struct. My final goal is to get the sched_entity of the task group_leader containing the task with this shed_entity :>

Comment: This may help [task_struct process list example](http://tuxthink.blogspot.in/2011/03/using-foreachprocess-in-proc-entry.html)

Comment: @Richard Chambers  Thanks.It's helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Linux kernel code provides a standard way to take a pointer to an element contained within a structure, and get back a pointer to the containing structure: the [`container_of`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.4.4/include/linux/kernel.h#L673) macro, which is used extensively throughout the kernel.

In this case, if you have a `struct sched_entity *foo`, you can get the enclosing `task_struct` with:

```
struct task_struct *task = container_of(foo, struct task_struct, se);
```

(Obviously this is only safe if you know for sure that the original `struct sched_entity *` pointer is pointing to a `struct sched_entity` which is inside a `struct task_struct`, so be careful...)

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. Let me have a try.

Answer (score 0):

`task_of()` macro in `kernel/sched/sched.h` file can help. It's basically calls `container_of()`.